# Exception while closing command context: ENGINE-01011 Cannot deploy process definition '<Location of BPMNFile>.bpmn'

Tags: spring, camunda, bpmn

I am encountering this error in Camunda while trying to start our spring microservice for it.

> ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: ENGINE-01011
> Cannot deploy process definition '.bpmn': there
> already is a message event subscription for the message with name
> ''.","exception":"org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException:
> ENGINE-01011 Cannot deploy process definition

I encountered this error when I refactored some codes in the bpmn file and it so happen that a unique identifier of sort remained but all others were changed. I was initially able to run my old bpmn changes not untill i refactored really. To my surprise, one of our senior devs assured me that my refactored code works perfectly on his side when he run it for the first time. My assumption was some old camundan config or db somewhere is causing this issue as it kept on mentioning a workflow that no longer exist even on code.

My assumption for the fix was to reset everything related to camunda. I already reclone our repository for the microservice. I also update the camunda dependencies to 7.19.0.  I also deleted all related database I know for the service and recreated it, yet I am still encountering this error. DOes camunda track this old process definitions somewhere else?, how do I reset it for it to be able to run on my local machine without saying this process def/message event subscription already exist?.

QAs already marked this implementation as working already, yet, on my side to where I developed and refactored the bpmn files, I could still not make it work.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

BPMN File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:modeler="http://camunda.org/schema/modeler/1.0" id="Definitions_1rrow5o" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="5.13.0" modeler:executionPlatform="Camunda Platform" modeler:executionPlatformVersion="7.15.0">
  <bpmn:process id="tadc-sff-translation-process" name="tadc-sff-translation-process" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_1767kan" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Activity_106br0o" />
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="Start Message Event">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:formData>
          <camunda:formField id="inputSource" label="inputSource" type="string" />
          <camunda:formField id="paymentHubId" label="paymentHubId" type="string" />
        </camunda:formData>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_1767kan</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:messageEventDefinition id="MessageEventDefinition_0od7ejz" messageRef="Message_0f7tl8p" />
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="Activity_106br0o" name="TADC SFF Task" camunda:asyncBefore="true" camunda:asyncAfter="true" camunda:type="external" camunda:topic="tadcSff-topic">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:executionListener class="com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.delegate.TaskListener" event="start">
          <camunda:field name="processStatus">
            <camunda:expression>Started</camunda:expression>
          </camunda:field>
        </camunda:executionListener>
        <camunda:executionListener class="com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.delegate.TaskListener" event="end">
          <camunda:field name="processStatus">
            <camunda:string>Finished</camunda:string>
          </camunda:field>
        </camunda:executionListener>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_1767kan</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_13m69lo</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
    <bpmn:boundaryEvent id="Event_1d83r4k" attachedToRef="Activity_106br0o">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:executionListener class="com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.delegate.TaskListener" event="start">
          <camunda:field name="processStatus">
            <camunda:expression>Failed</camunda:expression>
          </camunda:field>
        </camunda:executionListener>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_16h4qsb</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:errorEventDefinition id="ErrorEventDefinition_1tx2sac" errorRef="Error_1fu5f6d" />
    </bpmn:boundaryEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_16h4qsb" sourceRef="Event_1d83r4k" targetRef="Activity_0e87iy9" />
    <bpmn:serviceTask id="Activity_0e87iy9" name="TADC SFF Validation Error" camunda:class="com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.delegate.ValidationErrorDelegate">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_16h4qsb</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0drhu8q</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:serviceTask>
    <bpmn:endEvent id="Event_1gfazvr">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_0drhu8q</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0drhu8q" sourceRef="Activity_0e87iy9" targetRef="Event_1gfazvr" />
    <bpmn:endEvent id="Event_1c8ak6d">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_13m69lo</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_13m69lo" sourceRef="Activity_106br0o" targetRef="Event_1c8ak6d" />
    <bpmn:subProcess id="Activity_1u1j6lt" name="TADC SFF Default Catch All Process" triggeredByEvent="true">
      <bpmn:extensionElements>
        <camunda:executionListener class="com.cwt.bpg.paymenthub.delegate.TaskListener" event="start">
          <camunda:field name="processStatus">
            <camunda:string>Failed</camunda:string>
          </camunda:field>
        </camunda:executionListener>
      </bpmn:extensionElements>
      <bpmn:startEvent id="Event_18rq3ue" name="Error Start Event">
        <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_03yxiu2</bpmn:outgoing>
        <bpmn:errorEventDefinition id="ErrorEventDefinition_1k5y9dw" errorRef="Error_005q9j2" />
      </bpmn:startEvent>
      <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_03yxiu2" sourceRef="Event_18rq3ue" targetRef="Activity_1pxfbee" />
      <bpmn:endEvent id="Event_0qptzl2">
        <bpmn:incoming>Flow_0c4c71v</bpmn:incoming>
      </bpmn:endEvent>
      <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0c4c71v" sourceRef="Activity_1pxfbee" targetRef="Event_0qptzl2" />
      <bpmn:serviceTask id="Activity_1pxfbee" name="Create service now Incident" camunda:type="external" camunda:topic="translator-service-now-topic">
        <bpmn:incoming>Flow_03yxiu2</bpmn:incoming>
        <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0c4c71v</bpmn:outgoing>
      </bpmn:serviceTask>
    </bpmn:subProcess>
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmn:message id="Message_0f7tl8p" name="tadc-sff-translator-workflow" />
  <bpmn:error id="Error_005q9j2" name="GENERIC_ERROR" errorCode="GENERIC_ERROR" />
  <bpmn:error id="Error_1fu5f6d" name="VALIDATION" errorCode="VALIDATION" />
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="tadc-sff-translation-process">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1aa5da3_di" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="179" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="162" y="142" width="72" height="27" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1n18ls2_di" bpmnElement="Activity_106br0o">
        <dc:Bounds x="428" y="77" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_0uzsttr_di" bpmnElement="Activity_0e87iy9">
        <dc:Bounds x="590" y="190" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1gfazvr_di" bpmnElement="Event_1gfazvr">
        <dc:Bounds x="792" y="212" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1c8ak6d_di" bpmnElement="Event_1c8ak6d">
        <dc:Bounds x="792" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_101vu5y_di" bpmnElement="Activity_1u1j6lt" isExpanded="true">
        <dc:Bounds x="300" y="330" width="492" height="220" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_0zkm8n2_di" bpmnElement="Event_18rq3ue">
        <dc:Bounds x="342" y="422" width="36" height="36" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="319" y="465" width="83" height="14" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_0qptzl2_di" bpmnElement="Event_0qptzl2">
        <dc:Bounds x="692" y="422" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_0gxmaz3_di" bpmnElement="Activity_1pxfbee">
        <dc:Bounds x="491" y="400" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_03yxiu2_di" bpmnElement="Flow_03yxiu2">
        <di:waypoint x="378" y="440" />
        <di:waypoint x="491" y="440" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0c4c71v_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0c4c71v">
        <di:waypoint x="591" y="440" />
        <di:waypoint x="692" y="440" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1c37y6s_di" bpmnElement="Event_1d83r4k">
        <dc:Bounds x="457" y="139" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_1767kan_di" bpmnElement="Flow_1767kan">
        <di:waypoint x="215" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="428" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_16h4qsb_di" bpmnElement="Flow_16h4qsb">
        <di:waypoint x="475" y="175" />
        <di:waypoint x="475" y="230" />
        <di:waypoint x="590" y="230" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0drhu8q_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0drhu8q">
        <di:waypoint x="690" y="230" />
        <di:waypoint x="792" y="230" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_13m69lo_di" bpmnElement="Flow_13m69lo">
        <di:waypoint x="528" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="792" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

Workflow Config

```
@Log
@Component
public class TadcSffTranslatorWorkflow extends WorkflowEngineProcessor<String> {

    public static final String PROCESSOR_WORKFLOW_NAME = "tadc-sff-translator-workflow";

    public TadcSffTranslatorWorkflow() {
        super(PROCESSOR_WORKFLOW_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is related to the implementation of Camunda when listening on a message in a start event:
Thinking rational, you would expect that ONLY the latest deployment is taken in consideration. Unfortunately, all old deployments are still being considered, and one of them is listening on your message name.

Someone proposed to use signals on https://forum.camunda.io/t/there-already-is-a-message-event-subscription-for-the-message-with-name/5266 , but you for sure do not want an outdated process being started by an event. Only chance is to remove all old deployments during deployment.